# Does Azure Data Factory support CDATA XML format?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

After some trial and error, and a support call to Microsoft's Data Factory team of engineers, supposedly the product does not support CDATA values returned in XML.

I am using a web sink using XML format to send SOAP headers, and return XML data that contains CDATA formatting. Everything comes back properly in my pipeline, except the XML values containing any sort of CDATA formatting.

Is there a known workaround for this within Azure or Data Factory itself?

Thank you

Comment: No, we can not achieve that in Data Factory. As you said, it's no supported.

Comment: @LeonYue do you know an alternate way to retrieve this data in Azure's software stack? Once retrieved I should be able to pass into Data Factory for additional transformation.